# OpenVPN client-connect Exit Code 1 Not Triggering client-disconnect Script

Tags: vpn, openvpn

In my `client-connect` script I will `exit 1` to indicate that authentication failed and to reject connection from client. Which works fine, the client will be unable to connect to the openvpn server if my `client-connect` script exits with 1 (i.e. `exit 1`). The clients connection log will look like this if I reject their connection by exiting 1 in my `client-connect` script

```
Fri Mar 29 20:43:15 2019 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Mar 29 20:43:15 2019 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
Fri Mar 29 20:43:15 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,auth-failure] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 29 20:43:15 2019 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:,RECONNECTING,auth-failure,,,,,
Fri Mar 29 20:43:15 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

The problem is that it appears the client will just continue retrying to connect to the server even if the `client-connect` script exited with 1. My `client-disconnect` script never gets called when the clients connection attempt is being blocked with `exit 1` in the `client-connect` script.

How can I prevent the client from retrying to connect/auth to server when `client-connect` exits with 1? Also, how can I ensure that my `client-disconnect` script gets called when I reject a clients connection by exiting 1 in `client-connect`?